# Scratch Org without Data.org enabled

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I got the issue that when I create my Scratch org it's created with the Data.com feature on.

Thing is, I'm implementing Continuous Integration using Bitbucket Pipline and when I tried to push my scratch org to the Sandbox Im getting an error because the Sandbox does not have Data.com fields.

How can I create a Scratch org without Data.com?

Comment: Problem solved!
I was creating a Developer Edition scratch org
In the project-scratch-def.json file I use to config my scratch org, I replaced:
{
  "orgName": "Strach-Name",
  "edition": "Developer",
}

with..

{
  "orgName": "Strach-Name",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
}

And Data.com fields are no longer added to the SObjects.

Comment: What objects and what fields are you noticing with the Data.com feature?